# How to create own Flutter Template

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I am wondering if I could create my own flutter template. just like android Native having in android studio.

flutter having a template selection in command,
eg `flutter create -t skeleton <project-name>`

I have my own project structure and I want to add my custom template with that command just like
`flutter create -t <my_custom_template> <project-name>`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's possible at the moment. The best way to go about it is to create a code snippet in Visual Studio Code or in Android Studio as explained in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g93mls_EJmU&ab_channel=VandadNahavandipoor

Answer (score 0):

Else you can create your own CLI.
[You can check this template that creates many boilerplate code for you using exactly this.](https://apparencekit.dev/)

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Answer (score 0):

Just a workaround for VS Code users.

We can:

1. Create a template project
2. Copy it to another folder
3. Open this folder in VS Code
4. Use [rename](https://pub.dev/packages/rename) package to rename app name and bundleId
5. Manually rename .iml file and name in pubspec.yaml
6. Optionally: If you get an error like "Cannot create link or file because it already exists" while building for Windows, delete windows/flutter/ephemeral folder

(I think something similar can be done in Android Studio as well).